# How to calculate a big combination $\binom nr$

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, numerical-methods

How to calculate a big combination such as $$\binom {10^{80}}{10^{10}}$$, using software or by hand, or at least can we get an acceptable approximation.

Comment: You can use Stirling's approximation. See the relevant Wikipedia page. This is the canonical approximation for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Stirling’s approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation); even the simplest form,

$$n!\approx\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}e\right)^n\;,$$

is fairly good. In your example you get

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{10^{30}}{10^{10}}&\approx\frac{\sqrt{2\cdot10^{30}\pi}\left(\frac{10^{30}}e\right)^{10^{30}}}{\sqrt{2\cdot10^{10}\pi}\left(\frac{10^{10}}e\right)^{10^{10}}\cdot\sqrt{2\left(10^{30}-10^{10}\right)\pi}\left(\frac{10^{30}-10^{10}}e\right)^{10^{30}-10^{10}}}\\\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot\frac{10^{3\cdot10^{31}-10^{11}+10}}{\left(10^{30}-10^{10}\right)^{10^{30}-10^{10}+\frac12}}
\end{align*}$$

for instance, if I didn’t make another silly algebra error.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I am not sure why $(10^{30}-10^{10})! \approx \sqrt{2 \cdot 10^{20} \pi}(\frac{10^{20}}{e})^{10^{20}}$

Comment: @gobshubpang: Because I’m brain-dead tonight and made a very silly mistake; I’ll fix it right away.